# How do I slide the objects away from each other on a axis?

Tags: mesh, objects, transforms, axis

[image]

I have these two columns that I want to slide away from the centre on the y axis. how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't in *Edit* mode, unless you've already symmetrized on Y, in that case you can use the Y *Mirror* option on the top right.
Or make the changes, select all and *Mesh > Symmetrize* on Y.
Or use a *Mirror* modifier.